# Export users and passwords from Active directory into PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am developing a web application for my university project this summer and I am looking for some advice, The web application is to be deployed in to a windows environment that has around 500 users. The users will need to login before they can access the web application, this is where my first problem appears.

Do I need a way to export the users from active directory with their passwords on a daily basis. However I know that passwords are stored as a hash not clear text so id have to mimic the hashing in my web app. So do I use LDAP to authenticate the users for me? I would appreciate some advice of maybe a link to a resource that anyone knows that would be worth me reading.

Note.
The web application will be made in PHP with a sql database running on a windows server inside the same domain.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has an [LDAP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) that allows you to interface the Active Directory without exporting it.

Here is an example of implementing an LDAP authentication through php:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/101525-ldap-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Since [PHP has libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) to assist you with interacting with LDAP already then that might be the way to go. Exporting and managing users yourself sounds like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Just contact the auth server using [PHP::LDAP](https://www.php.net/ldap). This [blog post](http://www.myhow2guru.com/archives/php-connect-to-ldap/) shows a good example.